# my laptop does not work when I turn it on

Tags: laptop, dell-inspiron, white-screen

I have Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Laptop,
While I was watching a video on YouTube, a white screen came up, everything was running the fan and the sound of the video I was watching, Nothing happened and I had to manually restart, now when I turn on the laptop, it runs for seconds the fan turns on then everything turns off, I tried all the solutions on the internet and nothing worked,
Sorry for any mistake my English is not very good

Answer (score 0):

Your computer needs professional repair.
Something went wrong and the computer doesn't boot now.

If I had to guess, I would say you had a power surge that fried your power supply.
But a professional would not need to guess, as he has the tools to analyze the problem.

If your area is prone to power surges, you might invest in a surge protector,
to avoid future harm to your computer.